# Change text color in tableview cell in didHighlightRowAt

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, textcolor

I have this code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didHighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let cell  = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
        cell!.contentView.backgroundColor = .blue
        cell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
        var cell2 = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! DataTableViewCell
       cell2.textLabel.textColor = UIColor.white
    }
```

The background change works fine, but the text color change does not work.

Does anyone know why and how to fix this problem?

Comment: try that code in this method cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: put this code cell2.textLabel.textColor = UIColor.white in cellForRowAtIndexPath method

Comment: What's your code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`? Especially the part where you configure `cell.textLabel` Is `cell.textLabel` nil?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor greencolor];

Comment: Your code is not formatted correctly and you have not explained how your code answers the question. Read the SO guidelines before posting.

Answer (score 2):

I think instead of writing these two lines:

```
cell!.textLabel?.textColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)
cell?.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
```

writing only a single line as:

```
cell.textLabel?.highlightedTextColor = .black
```

will work fine for you!

Comment: check it now, use highlightedTextColor instead of textColor

Answer (score 1):

Use this function in your `DataTableViewCell`

```
func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, 
       animated: Bool)
```

See [Apple Developer Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623280-sethighlighted)

Answer (score 1):

Try any one of these:

```
// set highlighted color in `tableView cellForRowAt indexPath`
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
 cell?.textLabel?.highlightedTextColor = UIColor.white
}
```

or try this

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell {


    // As an alternate of `tableView cellForRowAt indexPath`, label text highlighted color can be set in both these methods of cell - `awakeFromNib` and `prepareForReuse`
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.textLabel?.highlightedTextColor = UIColor.white
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        self.textLabel?.highlightedTextColor = UIColor.white
    }


    // or textColor can be directly set here 
    override func setHighlighted(_ highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setHighlighted(highlighted, animated: animated)
        self.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `tableView(_:didHighlightRowAt:)` function is part of the *Controller* domain of your app while setting colors is part of the *View* domain (as per Model—View—Controller pattern). To keep up a good separation of responsibilities you might want to consider changing colors outside of the controller, i. e. in the cell itself. For this to work, you would create a simple `UITableViewCell` subclass, like so:

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {
    class var reuseIdentifier: String { return "MyCell" }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        if selected {
            textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.white
        } else {
            textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
        }
    }
}
```

This way the cell itself (instead of the controller) handles its own graphical representation which is the recommended way.

Answer (score -2):

OK, this code works:

```
override func awakeFromNib () {
         super.awakeFromNib ()
         // Initialization code
         self.titleCell? .xtxtColor = UIColor.black
         self.titleCell? .highlightedTextColor = UIColor.white
  }

     override func setSelected (_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
         super.setSelected (selected, animated: animated)

         // Configure the view for the selected state
     }
    
    
     override func prepareForReuse () {
         super.prepareForReuse ()
         self.titleCell? .highlightedTextColor = UIColor.white
     }
```

Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: How can I do it? this is my first topic :)